# Tricky Python array sorting

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Currently, I'm loading in some data into memory of the form:

```
5.579158e-19    0   0
5.678307e-19    1   0
...
6.041513e-19    27  0
5.938317e-19    28  0
...
5.978803e-19    38  1
5.590008e-19    39  1 
5.588807e-19    0   2
5.670948e-19    1   2
...
```

and so on with the command:

```
import numpy as np
data_res = np.genfromtxt('/path/data.csv',delimiter=';', dtype = float)
```

What I want, is a 40x40 matrix `mat`, where the indices are the entries in the second and third columns. The first entry mat[0,0] = data[0,0] is easy, but the problem is that the list is not sorted and that the entries in the second an third columns are floats so I can't reference them in the slice.

I've tried a double for loop method but it does not work properly.

```
mat = np.zeros((40,40))

for k in range(0,40):
    for j in range(0,40):
        mat[k,j] = data_res[k*j,0]
```

Wouldn't this method work if the index ran from 1-40 and not 0-39?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop isn't working because of your `data_res[k*j,0]` isn't doing what I think you want it to do.

To get the desired result try `data_res[(k*40)+j,0]`.

```
dim = 40
mat = np.zeros((dim,dim))

for k in range(0,dim):
    for j in range(0,dim):
        mat[k,j] = data_res[(k*dim)+j,0]
```

This is based on the assumption that your indicies are in fact already are sorted. As ajcr points out, if they aren't you'll need a different approach.

**UPDATE**: The second example provided by hooked is a much cleaner way to do this, and a more robust solution.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with no explicit loops.  I'll use a smaller data set, and create a 10x10 array `mat`.  If an index (i,j) is not in the CSV file, `mat[i,j]` will be 0.

Here's the input file:

```
In [27]: !cat data.csv
0.1    0   0
0.2    1   0
0.3    7   0
0.4    8   0
0.5    8   1
0.6    9   1 
0.7    0   2
0.8    1   2
0.9    9   9
```

Use `genfromtxt` to read the data into a structured array with three fields, `values`, `i` and `j`.

```
In [28]: data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', dtype=None, names=['values', 'i', 'j'])
```

By using `dtype=None`, we're telling `genfromtxt` to determine the data type based on what is found in the file.  In this case, the `'values'` field will be floating point, and the fields `'i'` and `'j'` will be integer.

Create the array `mat`:

```
In [29]: mat = np.zeros((10, 10))
```

Assign the data to `mat`:

```
In [30]: mat[data['i'], data['j']] = data['values']

In [31]: mat
Out[31]: 
array([[ 0.1,  0. ,  0.7,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0. ,  0.8,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.3,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.4,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.6,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.9]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question then I guess you want to sort your array based on indices. For that you can use [`numpy.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort):

```
>>> arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4).astype(float)
>>> x, y = arr.shape
>>> indices = np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(x*y), (y, x))).T
>>> np.random.shuffle(indices)
>>> arr = np.hstack((arr.flatten()[:, None], indices))
>>> arr  # now this looks like your dataset, first column is data and other two are indices
array([[  0.,   1.,   3.],
       [  1.,   1.,   2.],
       [  2.,   3.,   0.],
       [  3.,   0.,   1.],
       [  4.,   0.,   0.],
       [  5.,   2.,   0.],
       [  6.,   0.,   2.],
       [  7.,   2.,   3.],
       [  8.,   3.,   2.],
       [  9.,   0.,   3.],
       [ 10.,   3.,   1.],
       [ 11.,   1.,   0.],
       [ 12.,   3.,   3.],
       [ 13.,   1.,   1.],
       [ 14.,   2.,   2.],
       [ 15.,   2.,   1.]])
>>> arr[np.lexsort((arr[:, 2], arr[:,1]))][:,0].reshape(4, 4)
array([[  4.,   3.,   6.,   9.],
       [ 11.,  13.,   1.,   0.],
       [  5.,  15.,  14.,   7.],
       [  2.,  10.,   8.,  12.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your matrix is so small (40x40) a pure python solution for reading the file and imputing into a numpy array might be better for you:

```
raw = '''5.579158e-19    0   0
5.678307e-19    1   0
6.041513e-19    27  0
5.588807e-19    0   2
5.670948e-19    1   2'''

import numpy as np
mat = np.zeros((40,40))

for line in raw.split('\n'):
    z,i,j = line.split()
    mat[int(i),int(j)]=float(z)

print mat
```

The example above uses a string to hold the data for an example of a file. If the file was called `data.txt` you would run instead:

```
with open("data.txt") as FIN:
    for line in FIN:
        z,i,j = line.split()
        mat[int(i),int(j)]=float(z)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
mat = np.zeros((40,40))

for i in range(0,len(data_res)):
    mat[data_res[1] , data_res[2]] = data_res[0]
```